# Why every all-day event is represented as 2 day event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using a script to download events from Google Calendar into a spreadsheet. I am having an issue where 'all day events' are coming in as 2 days, e.g.: all day event on 5/9/17 downloads into the sheet as 5/9/17-5/10/17.
Here's my code:

```
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
  var row=i+2;
  var myformula_placeholder = '';
  // Matching the "header=" entry above, this is the detailed row entry "details=", 
  // and must match the number of entries of the GetRange entry below
  // NOTE: I've had problems with the getVisibility for some older events not having a value, 
  // so I've had do add in some NULL text to make sure it does not error
  var details=[[
    events[i].getStartTime(), 
    events[i].getTitle(), 
    events[i].getAllDayStartDate(), 
    events[i].getAllDayEndDate(), 
    events[i].getLocation(), 
    events[i].getDescription(), 
    events[i].getId()
    ]];
  var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,7);
  range.setValues(details);
}
```

Any idea what might be happening here? Is this a bug or is there an error in my code? I guess a workaround solution could be to subtract 1 day from every `AllDayEndDate` number, but wondering why this even happens in the first place.

Comment: Successful call to events methods returns a response with both [start and end dates](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) as you can see in the events resource.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getAllDayEndDate()) it's normal behavior:

> Gets the date on which this all-day calendar event ends. (If this is
>   not an all-day event, then this method will throw an exception.) The
>   returned Date will represent **midnight at the beginning of the day
>   after the event ends** in the script's time zone. To use the calendar's
>   time zone instead, call getEndTime().